Bafflement on lemma 2 in TRPO paper
In the original paper, proof of $|\bar{A}(s)|\leq2\alpha\max_{s,a}|A_\pi(s,a)|$, where $\bar{A}(s)=\mathbb{E}_{\tilde{a}\sim\tilde{\pi}}[A_{\pi}(s,\tilde{a})]$ goes like this
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}\bar{A}(s)&=\mathbb{E}_{\tilde{a}\sim\tilde{\pi}}[A_{\pi}(s,\tilde{a})]\\&=\mathbb{E}_{(a,\tilde{a})\sim(\pi,\tilde{\pi})}[A_{\pi}(s,\tilde{a})-A_{\pi}(s,a)]\hspace{1cm}since\hspace{0.2cm}\mathbb{E}_{a\sim\pi}[A_{\pi}(s,a)]=0\\&=P(a\neq\tilde{a}|s)\mathbb{E}_{(a,\tilde{a})\sim(\pi,\tilde{\pi})|a\neq\tilde{a}}[A_{\pi}(s,\tilde{a})-A_{\pi}(s,a)]\\|\bar{A}(s)|&\leq\alpha\cdot2\max_{s,a}|A_\pi(s,a)|\end{split}\end{equation}$$
where $(\pi,\tilde{\pi})$ is an α-coupled policy pair if it defines a joint distribution $(a,\tilde{a})|s$, such that $P(a\neq\tilde{a}|s)\leq\alpha$ for all s. $\pi$ and $\tilde{\pi}$ will denote the marginal distributions of a and $\tilde{a}$, respectively.
I'm confused by the transition from the second term to the third term, since I've tried to expand the second term and got only this  $\mathbb{E}_{(a,\tilde{a})\sim(\pi,\tilde{\pi})|a\neq\tilde{a}}[A_{\pi}(s,\tilde{a})-A_{\pi}(s,a)]$.
$$
\begin{equation}\begin{split}\mathbb{E}_{(a,\tilde{a})\sim(\pi,\tilde{\pi})}[A_{\pi}(s,\tilde{a})-A_{\pi}(s,a)]&=\mathbb{E}_{(a,\tilde{a})\sim(\pi,\tilde{\pi})|a\neq\tilde{a}}[A_{\pi}(s,\tilde{a})-A_{\pi}(s,a)]+\mathbb{E}_{(a,\tilde{a})\sim(\pi,\tilde{\pi})|a=\tilde{a}}[A_{\pi}(s,\tilde{a})-A_{\pi}(s,a)]\\&=\mathbb{E}_{(a,\tilde{a})\sim(\pi,\tilde{\pi})|a\neq\tilde{a}}[A_{\pi}(s,\tilde{a})-A_{\pi}(s,a)]\end{split}\end{equation}
$$
Could anyone offer a more detailed derivation? Appericiate your times and efforts!
